# Return default styling to legend element

Tags: css, less, legend

My less file is set so that a legend that is a child of a fieldset has certain styles. I to make a legend.default that is a also a child of fieldset, but which will have its default styling. I don't want to list out every property and write in it's default styling. Is there a way to make this.legend.dafault not have any inherited styles or anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to actually revert a property to default, but you can use `:not` to define the styles only for the non-default legends.

```
fieldset legend:not(.default) {
  /* certain styles */
}
```

See [:not(X) on CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/not/). Note that this works fine in all major browsers if you use a simple selector like in the example. Complex selectors cannot be used yet as the argument for `:not()`, since no major browser supports it at the time of writing.

Personally, I'd rather define styling for a specific class, and add that class to the legends that you *do* want to style, instead of using this negation-solution, but I'll leave that decision to you.

Comment: `:not()` has barely any browser support at this time, see http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-not-sel-list

Comment: @RobertC That's about extended arguments (level 4). My example is with a simple selector (level 3), for which [support is pretty good](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/CSS/:not). That is: all major browsers, including IE9+. Please downvote only if you know what you're talking about. ^.^

Comment: Hey I appreciate you clarifying!  I've been operating under the assumption that `:not()` had poor support based on other SO answers covering the topic.  Knowing it has better support changes how I would approach a few projects!

Comment: @RobertC I must admit I thought the same until very recently. ;-)